# Is it possible to use SqlParameter in in a Transact-SQL query that uses local variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclient, sqlparameter

Let's say that I have a transact-SQL query that does something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 -- Table1 has an identity column for the primary key
(
   Table1Value1,
   Table1Value2
)
VALUES
(
   @Table1Value1, -- SqlParameter
   @Table1Value2 -- SqlParameter
)   
DECLARE @table1ID int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Table2 -- Table2 also has and identity column for the PK
(
   Table1ID -- Must have foreign key to Table1 record
   Table2Value1,
   Table2Value2
)
VALUES
(
    @table1ID,
    @Table2Value1, -- SqlParameter
    @Table2Value2  -- SqlParameter
)

DECLARE @table2ID int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Table3
(
   Table1ID, -- Foreign Key to Table1 record
   Table2ID, -- Foreign Key to Table2 record
   Table3Value1,
   Table3Value2
)
VALUES
(
   @table1ID, -- Foreign Key to Table1 record
   @table2ID, -- Foreign Key to Table2 record
   @Table3Value1, -- SqlParameter
   @Table3Value2 -- SqlParameter
)
```

Is there a way to make this work? Can you escape the local transact-sql variable names so they're ignored by whatever figures out the location of the parameters? Can you tell SqlClient to use something other than @ to identify parameters? Is there a way to make this work without using a stored proc or having to run subqueries?

Thanks.

Comment: They're separate things, as long as your script uses different names, parameters and local variables can coexist. Are you having a particular problem with that?

Comment: Are you submitting that as one _batch_ or as separate statements? The latter won't work.

Comment: @HABO one statement.

Comment: @Alejandro It says "Must declare scalar variable @table1ID". I changed it to separate the declaration from the assignment and it worked. Thanks for confirming that it should work.

Comment: Are you declaring and assigning more than variable in a single line?

Comment: @Charlieface The code above is exactly what I did, just redacted some. The parameters I added were just for the values named in the query.

Comment: Then I don't get what your issue is. I have never had such a problem. So long as you are not declaring your parameters a *second* time with the same name they should not clash with the parameters. By the way, you should preferably terminate all SQL statements with `;`

Comment: @Charlieface So you used SqlParameter and local Transact SQL variable where you declared them and assigned them in the same statement? I wonder if it's the version of SqlClient I'm using. That would be System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.2.

Comment: I cannot replicate. I suggest you go back and check your code again for misspellings or bad syntax. Make sure all statements end with `;` and make sure you are declaring the data types. If you are using a case-sensitive server collation then make sure when you are using the variable you specify it as an exact match on case.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for listening. I guess I've just been up too long and didn't notice a missing letter or something. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It had to have been a typo. I changed it back and now it works. The only lesson here is to not work 40 hours in a 48 hour period and that you can mix parameters with transact-sql local variables. :-)

I wouldn't be opposed to deleting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have client code like this (using C# as the example):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("exec Procedure @Var1, @Var2", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Var1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = var1Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Var2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = var2Value;  
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With a procedure including code like this:

```
-- declare an additional variable in the procedure
DECLARE @VAR3 NVarChar(40) = 'test Value';
SELECT @Var1, @Var2, @Var3;
```

The trick is if you want to declare a variable in your SQL code or procedure for use only within the procedure or script, don't also provide a parameter for it from the client, because that would be declaring the same variable twice.

Comment: I didn't provide a parameter for it from the client. Does that code you posted really work if you don't separate the assignment of @VAR3 from it's declaration?

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure for use local variables. A lone script line the one in the question is also perfectly valid.